# ScrolledWindow and wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a frame with a textctrl. When the mouse enters the textctrl (EVT_ENTER_WINDOW) I show a PopupWindow on top of the textctrl, and when the mouse leaves the popup (EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW) I hide it again.

Everything works fine, except when inside the PopupWindow there's a ScrolledWindow *with shown scrollbars*. The EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW gets fired when I move the mouse on top of a scrollbar, so it looks like wxPython thinks the scrollbars are not part of the scrolledwindow.. :/
I tried binding the event to the popup or the scrollwindow itself, but nothing changes.. Is there a way I could get around this?

Many thanks!

(wxPython 2.8.8.0 on Xubuntu 8.10)

Comment: Robin Dunn told me: "the same thing would happen with any other widgets that are on the scrolled window, just as the frame will get a EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW when the mouse moves into the scrolled window (assuming some portion of the frame was visible so it could have received an enter window event too)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robin Dunn told me: "the same thing would happen with any other widgets that are on the scrolled window, just as the frame will get a EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW when the mouse moves into the scrolled window (assuming some portion of the frame was visible so it could have received an enter window event too)"

Answer (score 0):

Since tooltips normally disappear when the user moves the mouse you could also bind to `EVT_MOTION` instead of `EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW` and hide the tooltip when the user moves the mouse.

Comment: Well in my case the popup is somewhat more complex that a tooltip, so I can't dismiss it on mouse move.. Anyway thanks for your time :)